# Conditional probability that second box is empty given first box is empty

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> James places $k$ objects into $n$ boxes at random. Given that the first box is empty, what is the probability that the second box is also empty?

So far I have got $p(\text{not empty}) = (n-1/n)^k$ and I'm not sure how to apply conditional probability to this?

Comment: If he had only $n-14 boxes, what is the probabiity that the first box is empty?